# Azure DevOps second Pipeline consuming artifact from another Pipeline is stuck in Job is pending

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are running a set of pipelines for our web .net applications. A triggering pipeline (build) is feeding another pipeline (release). The second, triggered, pipeline is stuck on a `job is pending`. We are using the cloud version of Azure DevOps and only 1 agent, hosted by azure.

The build pipeline (portion of that) is the following

```yml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

pr:
  - main

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  NUGET_PACKAGES: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.nuget/packages
  group: 'Global - BuildSet'

stages:
  - stage: build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build

        steps:
          - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
            displayName: 'NuGet tool installer'

          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache
            inputs:
              key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/packages.lock.json,!**/bin/**,!**/obj/**'
              path: '$(NUGET_PACKAGES)'
              cacheHitVar: 'CACHE_RESTORED'

          - task: NuGetCommand@2
            displayName: 'NuGet restore'
            condition: ne(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, true)
            inputs:
              command: 'restore'
              restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
          -...
          - publish: $(Build.artifactstagingdirectory)
            artifact: $(ArtifactName)
```

The release pipeline is the following

```yml
trigger: none
pr: none
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: 'bak-ak'
      source: 'BAK - Build'
      trigger:
        branches:
          - main

parameters:
  - name: 'stages'
    type: object

    default:
      - stage: development
        dependsOn:

      - stage: staging
        variableGroup:
          - group: 'Staging - BAK'
          - group: 'Staging - BuildSet'
        dependsOn: 'development'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  NUGET_PACKAGES: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.nuget/packages
  group: 'Global - BuildSet'

stages:
  - ${{each stage in parameters.stages}}:
      - stage: ${{ stage.stage }}
        variables:
          - group: '${{ stage.stage }} - BAK'
          - group: '${{ stage.stage }} - BuildSet'
        dependsOn: ${{ stage.dependsOn }}
        displayName: Release
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)

        jobs:
          - deployment: ${{ stage.stage }}
            displayName: ${{ stage.stage }}
            environment: ${{ stage.stage }}
            strategy:
              runOnce:
                deploy:
                  steps:
                    - download: 'BAK-Release'
                      artifact: $(ArtifactName)

                    - task: ExtractFiles@1
                      displayName: 'Extract files'
                      inputs:
                        destinationFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(ArtifactName)'
                        archiveFilePatterns: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(ArtifactName)/**/*.zip'
                        cleanDestinationFolder: false
                    -...
                    - task: AzureWebApp@1
                      displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
                      inputs:
                        azureSubscription: '$(AzureServiceConnection)'
                        appType: 'webApp'
                        appName: '$(WebAppName)'
                        package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(ArtifactName)'
```

Both the yml files are under the same git project, same folder, same Azure DevOps project. The idea behind the release pipeline is to be triggered by a successful build from Build pipeline, and deploy to N environments. The variables for each environment is under a library and the release pipeline has access to those variable groups. The release pipeline displays currently the two different stages by their correct names. I am able to download logs from within the release pipeline, and I can see all the variables are been substituted correctly. Unfortunately I cannot paste the logs from the release pipeline because it contains sensitive information.

The Build pipeline consumes the yml from `DeploymentConfiguration/build-azure-pipelines.yml` [Build pipeline yml location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcxVN.png)
And the Release pipeline consumes the yml from `DeploymentConfiguration/release-azure-pipelines.yml` [Release pipeline yml location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80giN.png)

Both the Build and Release pipeline have set as main branch the current branch I am working with (not main). [Build pipeline branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlWNB.png) [Release pipeline branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brWWv.png)

I have created a PR to main and when I am pushing on the branch, the build pipeline triggers a build and upon completion, the release pipeline starts but hangs afters 2 seconds.

Anyone has an idea of what is wrong and the pipeline gets stuck? I'm out of ideas at this point.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem with my setup.

When the resource is defined in the second pipeline, an auto download artifact is triggered. That means that the `release pipeline` does not need the step

```yaml
                    - download: 'BAK-Release'
                      artifact: $(ArtifactName)
```

Not only that, the download string must be the same name as the release resource, in my case it should have been `bak-ak`. Ref:

```yaml
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: 'bak-ak'
      source: 'BAK - Build'
      trigger:
        branches:
          - main
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20logs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) is the Rest API: Builds - Get Build Logs, you could use this API to get every build task log.

Have you tested your nuget config locally?